# Adding key bindings for "Fn" + "Control" key in openbox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

I need use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> as a key combination, but it doesn't work in openbox (works in XFCE / KDE4`).

```
<keybind key="Fn-C">
  <action name="ToggleMaximize">
      </action>
</keybind>
```

The action name is totally right, it works with other key combination, e.g `W-3`.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Might I ask how you tried configure the key binding with `XF86WakeUp`?

Answer (score 3):

Different window managers can use different keyboard mappings, and the keymapping defines how your <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is recognized. This is why what works in XFCE doesn't necessarily work in Openbox.

To check how X (and Openbox) interpret your <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, follow [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys#Check_for_scancodes).

Based on the results, you can either use the appropriate key symbol in `rc.xml` instead of <kbd>Fn</kbd>.
<kbd>Fn</kbd> on my Thinkpad is recognized as `XF86WakeUp` for instance. If it has no symbol assigned, you can assign one manually with xmodmap as per [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys_in_Xorg) and then use that symbol in `rc.xml`.

Investigating further, it turns out that Fn is a special key on some notebooks (like IBM/Lenovo Thinkpads) in that the `Keypress` and `Keyrelease` events (or `Keydown` and `Keyup` in Microsoft terms) are generated simultaneously and only when the key is released. Further keypresses while <kbd>Fn</kbd> is depressed are simply not registered*. With [xev](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xev/), you can easily check if this is the case with your system as well.

This means that <kbd>Fn</kbd> cannot be used as a modifier key (combined with other keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>). It can be assigned as a shortcut on its own though. Combined with [Openbox's keychains](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings#Key_chains), this is almost as good as using it as a modifier. You just have to release it before pressing the key you combine it with.

* There must be *some* way of registering keys combined with <kbd>Fn</kbd> though at least on Thinkpads, as Lenovo's own Windows tools do react to <kbd>Fn</kbd> plus other keys. But this seems to happen at a very low level. When I am in a VMWare guest on a Windows host, pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> plus a key opens the appropriate tool in the Windows host, not in the guest OS. It would be interesting to look into the implementation of similar Thinkpad tools on Linux to see how they cope with <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

[Here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work) you find more Thinkpad-specific info on how <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> key combos generate ACPI events, which is what the Thinkpad tools react to. However, I suppose those events are only generated for specific combinations with <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys and not for other key combinations.

The page also describes how you can make ACPI events trigger key events. However, if <kbd>Fn</kbd> keydown and keyup don't generate separate events of their own (I believe they don't on Thinkpads), this doesn't really get you any further.

Comment: Yep, It was recognized as `XF86WakeUp`, but doesn't work either ;-(

Comment: Updated my answer with info on why you cannot combine `XFWakeUp` with other keys.

Comment: What I overlooked was that Fn+Ctrl worked for you in XFCE/KDE. It would be really interesting to see if xev output is different between those two and Openbox. What's the make of your notebook (or keyboard if it's not a notebook) anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I left minimalisting window managers like fluxbox/openbox and such, but here's some tips I recall:

1. You can actually see what keycode a certain keystroke combination rises using **xev**(1)
2. You can use use **xmodmap**(1) to bind certain keycodes to X events.

Look look at manpages for xev and xmodmap ;)